# How to suppress verbose list of remaining jobs if Snakemake job failed?

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

Since about version 7.0.0 of Snakemake, when a Snakemake job fails, a rather verbose list of remaining outputs is printed to the terminal.

This can be useful, but when you have a large workflow with thousands of jobs, it makes it really hard to see which job failed and why.

I would hence like to suppress this `Remaining jobs` output. How do I do this?

I had a look at the snakemake docs but couldn't find anything.

This is the section that I would like to get rid of through CLI flag/config, if possible.

[image]

Comment: It's related to a bug where snakemake would quit too early, and it's supposed to indicate this happenend. The message starts with take a look at: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/823. Might be related to running snakemake with the --keep-going flag. Seems like you can't turn it off, and it's probably a bug that it is being printed

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like it could be fixed in 7.8.1, let's see... https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1687